# Visual Studio - go to hidden member

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way, either by hotkey or context menu to navigate to the hidden member/method from it's override?

```
public void Test() {

}

// derived class
public void Test() {
    // "The keyword 'new' is required on 'Test' because..."
}
```

Reason is I need to make some of the base methods virtual in order to override them. So it would be nice to be able to access them directly instead of browsing through pages of code to find the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on method in derived class and press `Ctrl + ,`. This works for me in VS2012.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the *Go-To-Definition-Over-the-Solution*

- `Shift F12`
- `Control ,`
- Or use the `Control Shift F`

note that all of these need to click on the method or copy paste it to that

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. add an explicit call to the hidden member:

```
    // derived class
    public void Test() {
        base.Test();
    }
```

2. click on the newly added line, and `Toggle bookmark (CTRL+B, T)`
3. keeping the cursor on the new line, `Go to definition (F12)`
4. the cursor will be moved to the hidden member
5. `Toggle bookmark (CTRL+B, T)` on the hidden member, then return to the derived method through `Previous bookmark (CTRL+B, P)`
6. `Toggle bookmark (CTRL+B, T)` to get rid of te bookmark
7. `NExt bookmark (CTRL+B, N)` to return to the hidden member
8. `Toggle bookmark (CTRL+B, T)` to get rid of the bookmark
9. Edit the code

Recapping the keystrokes:

[after adding `base.Test()` in the derived class' method]
(CTRL+B, T), (F12), (CTRL+B, T), (CTRL+B, P), (CTRL+B, T), (CTRL+B, N), (CTRL+B, T)